# Optimizing (Large) Table Searches

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to posting on reddit (been reading posts though). I've been trying to sharpen my SQL skills and ran into the following.
There is a table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Positions]( 
  [load_id] [int] NOT NULL, 
  [acct_cd] [varchar](20) NOT NULL, 
  [acct_num] [varchar](255) NULL, 
  [sec_id] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, 
  [long_sht_cd] [varchar](3) NOT NULL, 
  [sedol] [varchar](15) NULL, 
  [isin] [varchar](15) NULL, 
  [cusip] [varchar](9) NULL, 
  [sec_type] [varchar](8) NULL, 
  [sec_name] [varchar](100) NULL, 
  [currency_cd] [varchar](3) NULL, 
  [total_holding] [decimal](18,4) NULL, 
  [mkt_price] [float] NULL, 
  [datetime_stamp] [datetime] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [pk_Positions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
  [load_id] ASC, 
  [acct_cd] ASC, 
  [sec_id] ASC, 
  [long_sht_cd] ASC) 
)
```

Table holds account positions data that are appended to multiple times a day. There are currently some 24 million rows in the table. Every time we append additional positions we add approximately 32,000 entries to this table, and all 32,000 entries will have the same load_id. The load_id is incremented by one each time we load a batch of 32,000 entries (i.e. the first 32K entries have load_id=1, the next 32K has load_id=2, etc...).

The datetime_stamp field shows the time at which the entries were loaded and is the same for all 32K entries in a single load.
For example, today, positions were first loaded into the table at 9am etc. At the end of the day we want to know what positions were loaded at 9 am.

What's the most efficient way to retrieve the first position load of the day given the above table definition?

My initial (simplistic) answer would be to simply

```
SELECT * FROM Positions 
WHERE datetime_stamp = todays_date_9am;
```

But I know I'm being naive. The table is massive, so I know I should be able to take advantage of the "load_id" hoping to make the search O(1) instead of anything lengthier.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: You can add an index on the `datetime_stamp` column to improve the performance of the query you presented.

Comment: You could also hold a smaller table with just load_id and datetime_stamp and populate that each time you do a load.  Then you can retrieve load_id from there first and then query Positions based on the load_id.  Without knowing your system is it worth archiving older rows to a separate table, you could still query across the complete set with a UNION but you'd improve performance on recent data.

Comment: This site isn't reddit.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following :

```
1) SELECT top(1) * FROM Positions 
WHERE datetime_stamp = todays_date_9am;
```

2) This will give you first record where datetime_stamp  is equal to datetime_stamp of 9 AM Load. You will get the LoadId of 9 AM load from this record.

3) As the LoadId is part of primary key, now you can get the required records using this LoadId.

```
select * from   Positions 
WHERE LoadId = 9_AM_LoadId
```

Comment: Without an index on datetime_stamp that's going to do a table scan anyway.  At least do select top(1) loadId to reduce the data travelling over the network.  You'd be better off following my suggestion in the comment of storing the loadid against load timestamp in a separate table.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder: It is not going to do whole table scan, but just pick the first record for which timestamp is matched. It is not going to create much load on the server.

Comment: But how will it find that row?  There isn't an index so the first query is going to have to scan the whole table until it finds a match on the datetime_stamp, if you're lucky it'll find it early on but the odds are against that.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_Positions_datetime_stamp
ON [Positions] ([datetime_stamp]);
```

This index will support the following query:

```
SELECT
    MIN([load_id]) AS StartID
FROM
    [Positions]
WHERE
    [datetime_stamp] = todays_date_9am;
```